# Use of "either/or" in a negative phrase

Tags: grammar, rules, negative-polarity-items

I'm not sure if a sentence I wrote is correct:

> "The last one didn't get neither my changes nor thiago's".

I'm trying to say that the last activity I ran in a system didn't get the changes I sent and also it didn't get thiago's changes.

Since I'm using the "didn't', I'm not sure if I should use 'neither/nor' instead of 'either/or'.

Is there a rule for this situation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> The last one didn't get my changes or thiago's

Single negative applied to a combination joined by *or*.

> The last one didn't get either my changes or thiago's

As above, but using *either* to make it clearer what the *or* is joining.

> The last one got neither my changes nor thiago's

Made negative by *neither...nor*.

> The last one didn't get either of my or thiago's changes.
>
> The last one got neither of my nor thiago's changes.

Another approach to the same thing, using *either...or* and *neither...nor* slightly differently.

> The last one didn't get my changes, nor thiago's.

*Nor* used without *neither*. This is rarer, though it can happen when speaking because you add it as an afterthought.

Note that all of these variants either use *didn't* or use *neither*, but none of them use both as yours did.

Answer (score 2):

Your sentence creates a double negative, which is not grammatical in Standard English. It has one or two other problems too. It’s difficult to know the exact meaning you want to convey, but a native speaker might say something like:

> The last one didn't get my change, and didn’t get Thiago’s either.